# How to define and work with temporary graphics data?

Tags: graphics, programming

Background: I am working on a program that produces design patterns ( using wallpaper-  and frieze-group theory ). This is for example a 'generating region' for a frieze or a wallpaper.

```
   Graphics[Polygon[{{.1, .1}, {.3, .8}, {1, .1}, {.5, .5}}]]
```

In reality this piece of Mathematica Graphics code is the result of many ( matrix- ) calculations.

Usually I want this in a larger size, for example 1 by 2:

```
   Graphics[{Polygon[{{.1, .1}, {.3, .8}, {1, .1}, {.5, .5}}], 
    Polygon[{{1.1, .1}, {1.3, .8}, {2, .1}, {1.5, .5}}]}]
```

Currently I work as follows: ===pseudocode=== follows:

```
  Map[ CalculateBaseMotif[#1,#2] &, 
       Flatten[Map[# &, Table[{ii, jj}, {ii, 1, lenX}, {jj, 1, lenY}]], 1]
```

So `CalculateBaseMotif` is calculated over and over. While all I want is to transtlate the result of

```
   G=Graphics[Polygon[{{.1, .1}, {.3, .8}, {1, .1}, {.5, .5}}]].
```

Summarizing: I make a ( complicated ) graphic G requiring many calculations of width W and height H. Then I want to produce a ( final ) graphic like so:

```
  GGGG
  GGGG
```

thus having width 4 x W and height 2 x H in the most efficient manner.

**Question: How to define and work with temporary graphics data ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Translate` for this, e.g.

```
With[{w = 5, h = 4, gr = Polygon[RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]]},
 Graphics[Translate[gr, Tuples[{Range[w], Range[h]}] - 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This will speed up things nicely.

Comment: I like the `Tuples` iterator. Would have gone for a `Table` out of old ingrained procedural habit.

Comment: There's a problem with geometric transformations in graphics: `ToBoxes` processes them using some recusrive function, so if we try to make more than ~`$IterationLimit/2` copies (4096 by default) of an object using e.g. `GeometricTransformation`, then it will fail. I hit this problem a few days ago, in 3D: `Graphics3D@
 GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], 
  TranslationTransform /@ N@Tuples[Range[14], {3}]]`.  Strangely `Translate` doesn't have the problem...

Comment: Since `Range` is `Listable` you could write:  `Tuples @ Range @ {w, h}`  (+1)

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you think this `$iterationLimit/2` limit should be reported as a bug?

Comment: @Jens I would think so but I'm not sure ... 2048 is an awful lot of transformations.  Also, I didn't test that it is *precisely* $IterationLimit/2, but it's close to that

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I checked whether there is a failure due to `$IterationLimit` if one re-casts the tiling using `GeometricTransformation`. Although there is indeed a problem in 3D graphics if you tile more than `4096` (by default) 3d objects, as mentioned by @Szabolcs in the comment to Heike's answer, that fortunately doesn't seem to happen for the 2D graphics in this question.

Here is a test where I decided to use the `at` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5650/245), defined as follows

```
at[position_, angle_: 0][obj_] := 
 GeometricTransformation[obj, 
  Composition[
   TranslationTransform[position], 
   RotationTransform[angle]
 ]
]

With[
 {
  w = 8, h = 8,
  gr = {Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {.1, .2}]}
 },
 Graphics[
  Map[(gr // at[#, ArcTan[Sin[#[[1]]]/Cos[#[[2]]]]]) &,
   Tuples[{Range[w], Range[h]}] - 1]]]
```

[image: tiling]

If you increase `w` and `h` to `70` both, it takes much longer but still works.