# Circuit drawing in Mathematica

Tags: physics, visualization

This past semester I taught an introductory electromagnetism course and had quite a nice time using Mathematica to draw all sorts of figures and diagrams (mostly for problems and etc.). However, I was unable to create a nice environment for the basic circuit elements such as resistors, capacitors, etc.

A Resistor, for instance, was annoying to draw a single one by hand. But after that, ideally, I would have liked to have a function `Resistor[{p1,p2}]` which functions exactly like the `Line` function but gives a line with a resistor in it (labels are not necessary since they can easily be added latter with the `Text` function).

This function could then be readily generalized to a function `CircuitElement[{p1,p2},element]` where "element" stands for any element one has previously drawn.

I have had quite some difficulty with these kinds of functions, perhaps due to my lack of knowledge on computational geometry. I think this kind of functionality might be of interest to many people. So, any thoughts or tips on how to get started?

---

Additionally I would like to have output that is similar to the following:

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Not Mathematica-based, but as @StackExchanger pointed out, [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) lets you draw schematics and simulate the circuits, is free and runs entirely in the browser (no plugins), and can export your diagram to PDF/PNG/EPS/SVG, which seems to be the key requirement of the original question.

Comment: (@compumike's message, continued) ...I took two minutes and created [your XOR circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/hycuat/exclusive-or-xor-equivalent-circuit/). If the Mathematica-based requirement is flexible, then I suggest you take a look at the ["Good Tools for Drawing Schematics"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/) question over on the Electronics StackExchange site.

Comment: N.B. @compumike is a developer for CircuitLab.

Comment: Hi @JM, thanks -- I suppose a comment is more appropriate than an answer in this case.  I'm sure the question author would love to see a Mathematica-based solution that creates his XOR sum-of-products schematic, but this question has been open for many months and none of the answers seem to do that yet.

Comment: Note that a lot of the "answers" seem to not differentiate between logic gate diagrams and eletronic circuits which are totally different things.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I dug up some simple analog circuit design definitions that I sometimes use to make diagrams for classes or problem sets.

Mathematica is obviously very useful when you have to create iterative copies of circuit elements, as in this example (a chain of resistor-capacitor elements):

[image: RC chain]

Since this is for teaching purposes and not professional, you may forgive the slight deviations from engineering standards in the definitions that follow.

First: to explain how I specify such circuits, here is the syntax that generated the above picture:

```
display[
 Table[
  rcElement // at[{i, 0}], {i, 0, 17, 3}]
 ]
```

To elaborate on this, first note the `at` statement. It is universally used to specify the 2D position and (optionally) orientation of the circuit element that precedes it. The circuit element can be a composite object, as it is here in the form of `rcElement` - the repeating unit of the example.

To make a composite element, you need basic building blocks. Here are a few. The first two are the simplest possible: a connecting wire (`connect`) and a gap in a wire, i.e. an interruption where something else can be placed in the path of the wire: `gap`.

```
connect[pointList_] := {Line[pointList], 
  Map[Text[Style[
      "\!\(\*AdjustmentBox[\(\[Bullet]\),\n\
BoxBaselineShift->0.24615384615384617`,\nBoxMargins->{{0., 0.}, \
{-0.24615384615384617`, 0.24615384615384617`}}]\)", 
      FontSize -> 18], #] &, pointList[[{1, -1}]]]}

gap[l_: 1] := Line[l {{{0, 0}, {1/3, 0}}, {{2/3, 0}, {1, 0}}}]
```

The next definitions should be self-explanatory by their names:

```
resistor[l_: 1, n_: 3] := 
 Line[Table[{i l/(4 n), 1/3 Sin[i Pi/2]}, {i, 0, 4 n}]]

coil[l_: 1, n_: 3] := Module[{
   scale = l/(5/16 n + 1/2),
   pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1}, {5/
      16, -1}, {5/16, 0}}
   },
  Append[
   Table[BezierCurve[scale Map[{d 5/16, 0} + # &, pts]], {d, 0, 
     n - 1}],
   BezierCurve[scale Map[{5/16 n, 0} + # &, pts[[1 ;; 4]]]]
   ]
  ]

capacitor[l_: 1] := {gap[l], 
  Line[l {{{1/3, -1}, {1/3, 1}}, {{2/3, -1}, {2/3, 1}}}]}

battery[l_: 1] := {gap[
   l], {Rectangle[l {1/3, -(2/3)}, l {1/3 + 1/9, 2/3}], 
   Line[l {{2/3, -1}, {2/3, 1}}]}}

contact[l_: 1] := {gap[l], 
  Map[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], FaceForm[White], 
     Disk[#, l/30]} &, l {{1/3, 0}, {2/3, 0}}]}
```

These all create graphics directives which can receive an optional argument `l` that sets their length (and will cause them to scale if `l` is different from `1`).

Now I need some commands to glue things together and display them:

```
Options[display] = {Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
   PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic};
display[d_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics[Style[d, Thick], 
  Join[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]], Options[display]]]

at[position_, angle_: 0][obj_] := 
 GeometricTransformation[obj, 
  Composition[TranslationTransform[position], 
   RotationTransform[angle]]]

label[s_String, color_: RGBColor[.3, .5, .8]] := 
  Text@Style[s, FontColor -> color, FontFamily -> "Geneva", 
    FontSize -> Large];
```

If I haven't forgotten anything, this should now be sufficient to draw some basic circuits:

```
display[{
  battery[] // at[{0, 0}, Pi/2],
  connect[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}}],
  resistor[] // at[{2, 2}],
  connect[{{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}}],
  coil[] // at[{4, 0}, Pi/2],
  connect[{{4, 0}, {4, -1}, {3, -1}}],
  capacitor[] // at[{2, -1}],
  connect[{{2, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: LRC circuit]

I forgot the switch, but you get the idea. Try replacing the battery by a `contact` to see how it works.

Coming back to the circuit at the beginning, what I did there is to repeat the following composite element several times:

```
rcElement = {connect[{{0, 2}, {1, 2}}],
   resistor[] // at[{1, 2}],
   connect[{{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}}],
   capacitor[] // at[{3, 0}, Pi/2],
   connect[{{3, 0}, {3, -1}, {0, -1}}]
   };
```

There is no limit as to the circuit elements you can define, of course. The main thing is that you need a convention for where their input and output terminals are. The placement with the `at` command defined above is very convenient for creating circuits textually, I think - at least once you get used to visualizing the coordinate system. That's why I draw the grid lines to help me visualize the correct placement.

**Edit**

I've updated the definition of `display` to accept all the options that are valid for `Graphics`. Also, here are some more definitions: a switch, ammeter and voltmeter. The illustration below also uses the `label` function that was already included in my original post:

```
switch[l_: 1] := {Line[{{0, 0}, {1/10, 0}, {1/10, 0} + 
     4/5 {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}], Line[{{9/10, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
  Map[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], FaceForm[White], 
     Disk[#, l/30]} &, l {{1/10, 0}, {9/10, 0}}]}

meter[l_: 1] := {Line[{{0, 0}, {1/10, 0}}], 
  Line[{{9/10, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  {EdgeForm[Directive[Black]], FaceForm[White], Disk[{l/2, 0}, 2/5 l]}}

ammeter[l_: 1] := {meter[] // at[{0, 0}],
  label["A", Black] // at[{l/2, 0}]}

voltmeter[l_: 1] := {meter[] // at[{0, 0}],
  label["V", Black] // at[{l/2, 0}]}

display[{
  switch[] // at[{0, 0}, Pi/2],
  connect[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}}],
  resistor[] // at[{2, 2}],
  connect[{{3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}}],
  coil[] // at[{4, 0}, Pi/2],
  connect[{{4, 0}, {4, -1}, {3, -1}}],
  connect[{{0, 0}, {0, -1}, {1/2, -1}}],
  battery[] // at[{1/2, -1}],
  connect[{{3/2, -1}, {2, -1}}],
  ammeter[] // at[{2, -1}],
  connect[{{4, 2}, {6, 2}, {6, 1}}],
  connect[{{4, -1}, {6, -1}, {6, 0}}],
  capacitor[] // at[{6, 0}, 90 Degree],
  label["L"] // at[{4.5, 1.2}],
  label["C"] // at[{6.5, 1.2}],
  label["R"] // at[{1.5, 2.5}]
  },
 GridLines -> None,
 Frame -> False,
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: labeledcircuit]

Comment: Nice, this almost feels like TikZ :)

Comment: Wow. This is awesome Jens. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @GabrielLandi Thanks - I've added some more definitions and an example. The proportions of the circuit elements could still use some adjustments, and of course I had to use US American symbols (e.g. for the resistor)... those things should be easy to adjust to your taste, I hope.

Comment: Very nice framework!

Answer (score 27):

[**SystemModeler**](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/features/) is one of the Wolfram products that allows building and simulating complex electric circuits - stand alone or as coupled to other systems, like thermodynamic or mechanical ones.

This is an alternative answer. If you have latest SystemModeler 4 you can visually create a model there and then import it into Mathematica:

```
Needs["WSMLink`"];
WSMModelData["MathematicaExamples.Modeling.ElectricCircuit.LowpassFilter"]
```

[image]

You can also create models in Mathematica programatically:

```
Needs["WSMLink`"];
components = {"R" \[Element] 
    "Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor", 
   "L" \[Element] "Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Inductor", 
   "AC" \[Element] "Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SineVoltage", 
   "G" \[Element] "Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground"};

connections = {"G.p" -> "AC.n", "AC.p" -> "L.n", "L.p" -> "R.n", "R.p" -> "AC.n"};

mmodel = WSMConnectComponents["SimpleCircuit", components, connections]
```

[image]

Also did you see the following *Mathematica* based application: [**Analog Insydes**](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/insydes/)? It is compatible with *Mathematica* 8. They I think not only visualize but also analyze circuits. This is a screenshot of their software:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here is some code excerpted from a larger project I am working on in which I used the built in `Graph` object to lay out the circuit.  This relieves me of having to manually position each node, but also leaves me at the mercy of the `GraphLayout` option.

```
componentlabelcolor = Blue; 
componentlabelsize = 0.5; 
componentlabelloc = 1; 

TransformComponentGraphics[pts_List, eg_] := 
Block[{}, {Line[pts], Translate[
 Rotate[Scale[eg, Clip[(1/4)*EuclideanDistance @@ pts, {0, 0.2}], {0, 0}], 
  {{1, 0}, -Subtract @@ pts}], Mean[pts]]}]

ComponentGraphics[_, tag_] := {Red, Rectangle[{-1, -0.5}, {1, 0.5}], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

ComponentGraphics["CurrentSource", tag_] := {White, EdgeForm[Black], 
Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2], Black, Arrowheads[0.06], Arrow[{{-(3/8), 0}, {3/8, 0}}], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

ComponentGraphics["VoltageSource", tag_] := {White, EdgeForm[Black], 
Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2], Black, First[Cases[Plot[(-(1/4))*Sin[4*Pi*x], 
   {x, -(1/4), 1/4}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2], Line[_], 4, 1]], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

ComponentGraphics["Resistor", tag_] := {White, EdgeForm[Black], 
Rectangle[{-1, -(1/4)}, {1, 1/4}], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

ComponentGraphics["Capacitor", tag_] := 
{White, Rectangle[{-(1/8), -(1/2)}, {1/8, 1/2}], Black, 
Line[{{-(1/8), -(1/2)}, {-(1/8), 1/2}}], Line[{{1/8, -(1/2)}, {1/8, 1/2}}], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

ComponentGraphics["Inductor", tag_] := 
{White, Rectangle[{-1, -(1/4)}, {1, 1/4}], Black, 
Table[Circle[{i, 0}, 1/4, {0, Pi}], {i, -(3/4), 3/4, 1/2}], 
Text[Style[tag, FontSize -> Scaled[componentlabelsize], 
  componentlabelcolor], {0, componentlabelloc}]}; 

draw = Function[{comp, tag, brs}, 
(Property[#1, {EdgeLabels -> Placed[tag, Tooltip], EdgeShapeFunction -> 
   (TransformComponentGraphics[#1, ComponentGraphics[comp, 
      tag]] & )}] & ) /@ brs];

Graph[Flatten[{Apply[draw, {{"VoltageSource", "V1", {1 -> 0}}, 
  {"Resistor", "R1", {2 -> 3}}, {"Inductor", "L1", {4 -> 5}}, 
  {"Capacitor", "C1", {6 -> 7}}}, {1}], {1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6}}], 
ImagePadding -> 10]
```

which yields

[image: circuit graph]

I suppose you could play with `VertexCoordinates` to get a more conventional layout, but my purposes required a completely automatic layout.

Answer (score 6):

Traditionally, circuits are described in Linear Algebra as networks, and networks as matricies, which gives you a way to find loops, isolate sub-nets, change voltage on any given link (or set it to 0 - a-la diode). But if all you need is logic, then Mathematica has logic functions which are fairly well structured:

```
Grid[{{"A", "B", "Output"}}~Join~Flatten[
     Table[{x, y, 
           Xor[x, y]},
           {x, {False, True}}, {y, {False, True}}]
     ,1], Frame->All]/.{False->0,True->1}
```

[image: Logical table]

of course you can chain things: `And[Xor[x,y],y]` or use infix form `(x~Xor~y)~And~y`:

```
Grid[{{"A", "B", "Output"}}~Join~Flatten[
     Table[{x, y, 
           Xor[x, y]~And~y},
           {x, {False, True}}, {y, {False, True}}]
     ,1], Frame->All]/.{False->0,True->1}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've never done so myself, but a search of the Wolfram Demos Project revealed this page, complete with demos using circuit diagrams. I hope it proves helpful: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Circuit+Design&limit=20

Answer (score 5):

Modelica is a general framework for simulation of physical systems (much like Simulink from Mathworks) and [MathModelica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6157/) is a Mathematica-compatible interface to Modelica.

Wolfram recently acquired MathCode.  Perhaps the next version of Mathematica will provide built-in support for physical systems modeling and simulation.

[CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) is not Mathematica-based, but is free and runs inside your browser.

Comment: Looking at [the website](http://www.mathcore.com/products/mathmodelica/mm2.1.php), MathModelica is not Mathematica-based. It can connect to Mathematica, _if_ you have a separate license.

Comment: @Jens:  Thanks -- edited response accordingly.

Comment: Now MathModelica has become System Modeler http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/ and it is a wonderful piece of software. Try it for free.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to explore [Analog Insydes](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/insydes/) which is a commercial add on developed by a Fraunhofer institute.

Also, the (OpenSource) [IMTEK Mathematica Supplement (IMS)](http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/imteksimulation/downloads/ims) does have a circuit simulator and provides functionality to draw circuits as well. Here are two simple circuits:

[image]

and

[image]

You can the perform, stationary, transient and/or harmonic analysis. System matrices are available also.

Comment: AnalogInsydes must be good, it costs $12,000.

Answer (score 2):

The author code from this demonstration might be useful
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrawYourOwnElectricalCircuit/