# How to plot electrical graph from given edges with some constraints?

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to create a graph like this automatically with edges given and need some help. The graph doesn't need to be exactly same but I would like to make some constraints for the generated graph. 
This is an example of edges of an electrical graph. And all the graphs have at most two voltage sources V1, V2 and some components may exist or not.

```
edges = {V1n <-> V2n, V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, 
   R3n <-> R4p, R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n, R2n <-> V1n};
```

[image]

The graph above is usually drawn like below as an electrical circuit but the style is complicated so it's not necessary to make it as below.

[image]

Here are some constraints:

1. If voltage source `V1` or `V2` exists then `V1` and `V2` should be drawn vertically on the left and right as in the figure.
2. Other vertices other than `V1p, V1n, V2p, V2n` should be drawn in the region between `V1` and `V2` as an example image.
3. Vertices associated the same components `{V1p, V1n}, {V2p,V2n}, {R1p, R1n}, {R2p, R2n}, {R3p, R3n}, {R4p, R4n}` should be placed next to each other. It would be nice if the edge length between vertices in each pair above are same as well (just to make the symbols same size and look nicer- so it's not required if it's complicated).

Here are some examples of expected graph (or something similar, no need to be exactly same) from given edges:

```
edges = {V1n <-> V2n, V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, 
   R3n <-> R4p, R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n, R2n <-> V2n};
```

[image]

Graph with `V1` removed:

```
edges1 = {R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, R3n <-> R4p,  R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n};
```

[image]

Graph with `V2` removed:

```
edges2= {V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, R3n <-> R4p};
```

[image]

Graph with both `V1` and `V2` removed:

```
edges3= {R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, R3n <-> R4p};
```

[image]

I have tried this (with help from my previous post) but got stuck on how to make graph with constraints above.

```
resistor[{a1_, a2_}] := 
 Block[{d, l, res, s, t}, d = a2 - a1; l = Norm[d]; 
  s = a1*(1 - 2/5) + a2*(2/5); t = a1*(1 - 3/5) + a2*(3/5); 
      res = 
   Line[Table[{Norm[t - s]*(i/16), (1/(6*l))*Sin[i*(Pi/2)]}, {i, 0, 
      16}]]; 
      res = 
   GeometricTransformation[res, 
    TranslationTransform[s] @* RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]]; 
      {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}]
dc[{a1_, a2_}] := 
 Block[{d, l, res, s, t, r}, d = a2 - a1; l = Norm[d]; 
  s = a1*(1 - 2/5) + a2*(2/5); t = a1*(1 - 3/5) + a2*(3/5); 
      r = Norm[s - t]/2; 
  res = {Circle[{r, 0}, r], Line[{{2*(r/4), r/4}, {2*(r/4), -r/4}}], 
          
    Line[{{{r/3 + r, r/4}, {r/3 + r, -r/4}}, {{r/3 + r - r/4, 
        0}, {r/3 + r + r/4, 0}}}]}; 
      res = 
   GeometricTransformation[res, 
    TranslationTransform[s] @* RotationTransform[ArcTan @@ d]]; 
      {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{a1, s}, {t, a2}}], res}]
edges = {V1n <-> V2n, V1p <-> R1p, R1n <-> R3p, R1n <-> R2p, 
   R3n <-> R4p, R3n <-> V2p, R4n <-> V2n, R2n <-> V1n}; 
coords = GraphEmbedding[edges]; 
vertexToCoords[{v1_, 
    v2_}] := {Position[VertexList[edges], v1][[1, 1]], 
   Position[VertexList[edges], v2][[1, 1]]}; 
Graph[edges, 
 Prolog -> {resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R1p, R1n}]]]], 
   resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R2p, R2n}]]]], 
       resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R3p, R3n}]]]], 
   resistor[coords[[vertexToCoords[{R4p, R4n}]]]], 
   dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V1p, V1n}]]]], 
       dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V1p, V1n}]]]], 
   dc[coords[[vertexToCoords[{V2p, V2n}]]]]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

There are some problems with the graph:

1. `V1` and `V2` are not placed vertically on the left and right.
2. Vertices of the same components are not placed near each other. For example `{R2p, R2n}` or `{R4p, R4n}`.

Comment: For [reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/circuit-drawing-in-mathematica). I think [Nodal](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2225/) was the original program to do circuit analysis that was bought by the company called AnalogInsydes but I cannot verify this. A [book](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/48/) also talked about this program, but this is old information.

Comment: @Syed yeah, I checked that before but I want to do it automatically instead of manually specifying the coordinates of each components as some components may not exists in the graph. Also I would like to make drawing in the form of graph as above as from that I can extract some information as well.

Comment: @Syed the book looks interesting but I think that is a different problem. My goal now is just for ploting and display the graph with some constraints instead of solving the circuits.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `EdgeShapeFunction` to have more systematic approach.
You can use `esf[#1, #2, 4, Reverse]` with `Reverse` as its fourth argument to achieve swapping of `+-` to `-+` of DC sources or to swap orientation of inductors as can be seen on the last image.

```
esf[pts_List, e_, n_, rev_ : Identity] := 
 Block[{s = 0.03, 
   symbols = {{Opacity[1], White, Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {2, 1}], Black, 
      Line[{{-2, 0}, {-(5/3), 2/3}, {-1, -(2/3)}, {-(1/3), 
         2/3}, {1/3, -(2/3)}, {1, 2/3}, {5/3, -(2/3)}, {2, 
         0}}]}, {Opacity[1], White, Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {2, 1}], 
      Black, Table[
       Circle[{2 k, 0}, 2/3, {0, \[Pi]}], {k, -(2/3), 2/3, 
        2/3}]}, {Opacity[1], White, Rectangle[{-1/4, -1}, {1/4, 1}], 
      Black, Thick, Line[{{-1/4, -1}, {-1/4, 1}}], 
      Line[{{1/4, -1}, {1/4, 1}}]}, {Opacity[1], White, 
      Rectangle[{-2, -1}, {2, 1}], Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 2], 
      Line[{{1/4, 0}, {5/4, 0}}], Line[{{3/4, -1/2}, {3/4, 1/2}}], 
      If[Round[pts[[1, 1]], 1/10] === Round[pts[[2, 1]], 1/10], 
       Line[{{-3/4, -1/2}, {-3/4, 1/2}}], 
       Line[{{-5/4, 0}, {-1/4, 0}}]]}}}, {Arrowheads[{{s, 0.5, 
      Graphics[symbols[[n]]]}}], Arrow[rev[pts]]}]

edges = GridGraph[{2, 4}] // EdgeList;
resistor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}};
inductor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {};
capacitor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {};
dc = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {7, 8}};

Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[{Range[4], Range[2]}], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {(Alternatives @@ 
      resistor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 1] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      inductor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 2] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      capacitor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 3] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      dc) -> (esf[#1, #2, 4] &)}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 
     4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}};
resistor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
inductor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};
capacitor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{3, 4}};
dc = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{5, 6}, {2, 4}};

Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding", 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {(Alternatives @@ 
      resistor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 1] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      inductor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 2] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      capacitor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 3] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      dc) -> (esf[#1, #2, 4] &)}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
edges = GridGraph[{2, 5}] // EdgeList;
resistor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 4}, {5, 6}, {6, 8}};
inductor1 = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 3}};
inductor2 = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{3, 5}, {9, 10}};
capacitor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{4, 6}, {3, 4}};
dc1 = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {7, 9}};
dc2 = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{7, 8}, {5, 7}};

Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[{Range[5], Range[2]}], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {(Alternatives @@ 
      resistor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 1] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      inductor1) -> (esf[#1, #2, 2] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      inductor2) -> (esf[#1, #2, 2, Reverse] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      capacitor) -> (esf[#1, #2, 3] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      dc1) -> (esf[#1, #2, 4] &), (Alternatives @@ 
      dc2) -> (esf[#1, #2, 4, Reverse] &)}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: The drawing looks really nice but would the coordinates of each elements are automatically asigned and satisfying some constraints above. For example, assume that I have a graph with two dc voltage sources V1, V2, one inductor L1 and one capacitor C1. So the vertices would be  V1p, V1n, L1p, L1n, C1p, C1n corresponding to their positive and negative terminal. Assume that I have the edges connection. Would it be automatically place these components so that V1, V2 is always on the left and right and vertices in the same pair {L1p, L1n}, {C1p, C1n} are placed near each other?

Comment: Something like in the image below. Assume that the edges are given. DC voltage sources V1, V2 may exist or not. Also some passive components may be removed or added. If V1 or V2 exist then I want to place V1 on the left, V2 on the right. And all passive components in the middle region between V1 and V2. (there are no other voltage sources other than V1 and V2). Also I want to make sure that vertices of the same components such as {V1p, V1n}, {V2p, V2n}, {L1p, L1n}, {C1p, C1n} are placed closed to each other. https://ibb.co/cCpJmPD

Comment: If I do it automatically then some cases for example L1p is placed on the left and L1n is placed very far away on the right so it looks bad.

Comment: It is easy - the two sources should always be placed on edge {1,2} and edge defined by last two vertices, say {9,10}, as can be seen on my last image.

Comment: But what if V1 or V2 or both of them doesn't exist in the edges. Probably I can write some condition to check if they're in the edges or not. Another problem is that the placement of vertices of the same elements like L1p, L1n. If you drawing manually it's easy to specify their positions to make them looks nice. However, if it's done automatically then L1p and L1n are probably placed very far from each other.

Comment: When there is no component on the edge then there is just a simple connection (wire), or if the whole edge is removed then there is nothing. What is the problem? You specify position of source by `dc = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {7, 8}};` - which means there is one on edge `{1,2}` and one on edge `{7,8}`. If it was `dc = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}};` then there is just one source on the edge `{1,2}`.

Comment: I got the idea. But the problem is that if you specify like `GridGraph[{2, 5}]` then you don't allow edge between `{3, 8}` for example a resistor between  `{3, 8}` . I tried `resistor = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}, {3,8}};` but it didn't work. I want to make it possible to connect beween any two vertices.

Comment: You have first to add edge to `edges` list and then you can place a resistor on it. But it would cross another existing edge so it would not look nice - but you did not specified in your question that you want also crossings of connections.

Comment: I thought it's too complicated to make them not crossing automatically so I didn't add that. It's ok to cross. Would there any method to make them not cross automatically (just curious) and some circuits that are impossible to make it not crossing?