How to insert a graphics between two points?
How can I insert the resistor between points {1,1} and {2,1} without modifying res (zoom is okay if needed)?
res = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
    Line[{{3, 0}, {4, 0}}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}, {3/4, -1}, {1, 0}, {5/4, 
       1}, {3/2, 0}, {7/4, -1}, {2, 0}, 
           {9/4, 1}, {5/2, 0}, {11/4, -1}, {3, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> 50];
Graphics[Inset[res, {1, 1}, Automatic, Scaled[1/5]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 300, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 3, 1], Range[0, 2, 1]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 3, 1], Range[0, 2, 1]}
 ]



It is possibly a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275636/53172

Does this answer your question? How to plot electrical graph from given edges with some constraints?

@azerbajdzan nice. Would be great if you could add switch as well.

First, remove any paddings and margins from res by setting PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> 0. Then specify the third argument of Offset as {-1, 0}, because this is where the left point of your resistor lies at.
res = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
   Line[{{3, 0}, {4, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}, {3/4, -1}, {1, 0}, {5/4, 
      1}, {3/2, 0}, {7/4, -1}, {2, 0}, {9/4, 1}, {5/2, 
      0}, {11/4, -1}, {3, 0}}]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ImagePadding -> 0]

Graphics[Inset[res, {1, 1}, {-1, 0}, 1], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}, Axes -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 400]

Additionaly, you can use the fourth argument of Inset if you want to have rotated resistors.
plotResistor[p1_, p2_] := 
 Inset[res, p1, {-1, 0}, EuclideanDistance[p1, p2], p2 - p1]

Graphics[{
  plotResistor[{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1}],
  plotResistor[{1/2, 1}, {1, 1}],
  plotResistor[{1, 1}, {2, 2}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400]


